# How to pass sys.argv array to os.system?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, command-line-arguments

I have two Python file named `file1.py` and `file2.py`. I run the `file2.py` in `file1.py`. But I can't send all command line arguments of the `file1.py` to `file2.py`.I tried `"$@"` to pass all arguments but it didn't work.

`file1.py` is like:

```
import os 

os.system("python file2.py %s" % "$@") #I want to pass all sys.argv with "$@" in here but It did't work
```

`file2.py` is like:

```
import sys

print ("file2.py ARGS:",(sys.argv))
```

First I run the `file1.py` from the `cmd` with some arguments like:

```
python file1.py a b c
```

It provided an output like this: `file2.py ARGS: ['file2.py', '$@']`

But I want the output should like this: `file2.py ARGS: ['file2.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']`

So, How can I pass `sys.argv` array to `os.system` in Python? (without array iterating in `for` loop)

Comment: Have you considered using `subprocess.call` instead? It's better suited for your example

Comment: No, But I don't want to use subprocess mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shlex.quote` to produce a string that you can safely pass to a subshell:

```py
os.system("python file2.py %s"
          % " ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv[1:])))
```

A better option to switch from `os.system` to the more powerful and robust `subprocess` module:

```py
subprocess.call(["python", "file2.py", *sys.argv[1:]])
```

Comment: `shlex.quote` doesn't take lists. You can use `shlex.join` for Python 3.8+ or `" ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv[1:]))` for 3.3+

Answer (score 0):

If bot scripts are python maybe you can create a function in `file2.py` to wrap its code, then import and execute from `file1.py`.

That way you avoid the system shell between the two scripts.